# How to manually select data/programs for SuperFetch

Tags: windows-7, superfetch

I've just learned about SuperFetch, and how it automatically loads frequently-used programs into memory so they load quickly on the first use.  It explains why my wife's piano sample instrument, which is ~4GB in size, sometimes takes up to a minute to load, and sometimes loads instantly.

I'd like to be able to manually earmark that piano sample for SuperFetch to always load, and load early, so she can rely on it being fast to load every single time.  It would significantly improve her workflow and her creativity to know that when she wants to start using the piano, she doesn't have to wait.

I suppose an alternative solution would be to automatically open the program with the sample loaded as soon as Windows starts.  However I'd like to use SuperFetch because it is purpose-built for this kind of use-case, and because it would be seamless, without altering her workflow or imposing any extra mental noise on her other day-to-day tasks.

Comment: It doesn't load `~60GB` to RAM, right? From what I understood, Windows takes care of what it caches and such using that mechanism based on when you use it, etc. Perhaps ensuring it's used at specific times consistently would help ensure it (or it's correlated files) get put into the cache for the mechanism to use it. That'd be interesting though if there were a way to manually set this. I know there's the `C:\Windows\Prefetch\Layout.ini` but I don't think that's for adding entries manually.... [SuperFetch: How it Works & Myths](http://www.osnews.com/story/21471/SuperFetch_How_it_Works_Myths)

Comment: Hmm... I don't think it could possibly load 60GB to RAM, you're right about that. I think her machine only has 16GB total anyway.  Sorry, I'll edit that, I think it's closer to 4-5GB that actually gets loaded at a time.  I believe the extra data is the same samples with different mic and lid positions, so it doesn't all need to be accessible at once.  The point stands though that it would be nice to have it available without the loading delay.  As far as I know she doesn't change those settings usually.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I forgot about this question.  I guess it does, since the answer is, "You can't do that."